# What does 'a' <= string[i] mean?

Tags: c++

I'm looking at a function:

```
bool StringWrap::isAlpha() const {
   int sz = st.size();
   for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
      if (!( ('a' <= st[i] && st[i] <= 'z')
            || ('A' <= st[i] && st[i] <= 'Z') ) ) {
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```

In this case `st` is a `string`. I was wondering what the logic statement `'a' <= st[i]` means? When I think of doing a less than or equals comparison, I think of numbers, not characters.

Comment: In C and C++, characters are numbers -- the ASCII code of the character.

Comment: Any C++ textbook should explain that.

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently reading Data Structures: Objects, Abstraction, and Design using C++. And one great way of learning things is by asking questions.

Comment: You need some basic proficiency in the language so you can ask reasonable questions, this is not a tutoring service.

Comment: @Barmar, Not necessarily ASCII codes, but most likely.

Comment: There really isn't anything unreasonable about this question. I don't view this as a tutoring service either.

Comment: @chris I know, I just didn't want to get into the details of different coding systems, they're not really relevant, especially to someone who doesn't even know that `char` types are numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
('a' <= st[i] && st[i] <= 'z')
```

This expression is testing whether `st[i]` is a lower-case character. Here are all ASCII characters:

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?
@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_
`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

These are the ones for which `'a' <= st[i]` ("at least `'a'`") is true:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

(Note how all characters below `'a'` are cut away.)

And these are the ones for which `st[i] <= 'z'` ("at most `'z'`") is true:

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?
@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_
`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

(Note how all characters above `'z'` are cut away.)

And finally, these are the ones for which both conditions are true:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

By the way, the method body can be simplified to a single line:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

bool StringWrap::isAlpha() const
{
    return std::all_of(st.begin(), st.end(), isalpha);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should explain _how_ the expression tests whether `st[i]` is lower-case? That's clearly what the OP doesn't understand.